# Извлечение расширения файла

Tags: delphi

В этом коде:

```
tmp := ExtractFileName(L.Strings[i]);
tmp := Copy(tmp, 1, Pos('.', tmp) - 1);
NewName := Format('%s%s.%s', [ExtractFilePath(L.Strings[i]),
                                 tmp,
                                 FormatDateTime('ddmmyy_hhnn', Now)]);
```

`ExtractFileName` Извлекает из полного имени файла краткое имя файла.
`ExtractFilePath` Извлекает из полного имени файла путь к файлу.

При обработке файла эта функция сохраняет новый файл без расширения. Как сделать что бы функция сохраняла с расширением ?

Я делала так:

```
tmp := Copy(tmp, 1, Pos('.', tmp) - 1);
NewName := Format('%sNew_%s', [ExtractFilePath(L.Strings[i]),
                                  ExtractFileName(L.Strings[i])]);
```

Программа сохраняет с расширением. Но тогда программа не генерирует новые имена а постоянно сохраняет файлы с именем `New_`. А нужно что бы с уникальными именами.

Answer (score 6):

Если Вам нужно к имени файла добавить дату не меняя расширения, то делается это так

```
NewName := ChangeFileExt(L[i], FormatDateTime('ddmmyy_hhnn', Now) + ExtractFileExt(L[i]));
```

- `ExtractFileExt` возвращает текущее расширение файла, включая точку
- `ChangeFileExt` заменяет текущее расширение файла, включая точку